# iOS - UIViewController - Runtime error when overriding a getter in UIViewController subclass chain

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

iOS newbie here.

I have a class that is a subclass of UIViewController called CommonVC. It does not have a scene directly associated with it. It declares a property in the .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeClass *someClass;
```

I modify one of my scene View Controllers to have CommonVC as the super class instead of UIViewContoller:

```
@interface SceneViewController : CommonVC
```

In SceneViewController, I create a lazy instantiation getter for the property:

```
- (SomeClass *)someClass 
{
  return self.someClass ? self.someClass :
  (self.someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithData:@"xxx"]);
}
```

This compiles OK, but crashes at runtime with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,...). The debugger is pointing at the override method and 'self' is nill (0x00000000).

The first reference to the getter (self.someClass) is in the viewDidLoad method. I would think that the view controller and its super class would have been instantiated at this point.

What is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
return self.someClass ? self.someClass
```

This is an endless loop. the code self.someClass is equivalent to [self someClass]; so that will get called endlessly. You will want to change your self.someClass to _someClass.

Comment: Thanks, I did originally have _someClass but the compiler gave an error. I added @synthesize and changed it back to _someClass and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you call self.someClass in your getter you end up in a loop as self.someClass it's actually calling that same method. This is probably the reason of your crash.

Secondly, every UIViewController instance always has a view (the scene you're talking about?) associated with it, hence all the -viewDidLoad, -viewWillAppear, etc. methods.

Lastly, it's very bad to have a 'common view controller' to handle stuff. You may want to use the delegation pattern or the singleton pattern instead.

Comment: Thanks. This is part of a class. I am still learning iOS. I'm sure better techniques will follow in the class, right now it's a huge learning curve. We have not yet gotten to delegates et.al.